# Using values read from arrays as variables

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have lots of arrays which are called r1, r2, r3, r4.... I have another array which holds values that correspond to these array names randomly stored. For example...

```
room_ID = [[r1, r2],  #array randomly holding these values
           [r3, r4]]

r1 = [[0, 1],
      [2, 3]]

room = room_ID[0][0]
print(room)
print(r1)
```

Output:

```
r1
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3]]
```

My wanted output would be for print(room) to print the same as print(r1) does. How can I make this happen? Even if I do...

```
room_ID = [[r1, r2],
           [r3, r4]]

r1 = [[0, 1],
      [2, 3]]

room = room_ID[0][0]
rooms = room
print(rooms)
```

I still get r3 as the output

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a dictionary to store the values of r1, r2, etc rather than variables. Not sure if that meets your needs. Here's simplified example.

```
rooms = {'r1':[some_list]}

list_of_rooms = ['r1']

print(rooms[list_of_rooms[0]])

#output: [some_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
room = global()[room_ID[0][0]]
print(room)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3]]
```